# How to simulate change event on a react-number-format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to simulate a change event to change the valeu of a react-number-format component within my component.

When I test the component, I get *TypeError: value.replace is not a function* on the simulate('change', event) method.

The NumberFormat component rendering inside the tested component:

```
<NumberFormat
  id="estimateLineQty"
  name="estimateLineQty"
  className="form-control input-sm"
  value={this.state.estimateLineQty}
  thousandSeparator=" "
  decimalSeparator=","
  decimalScale={2}
  onValueChange={values => {
    const { formattedValue, floatValue } = values;
    const newPrice = floatValue * this.state.estimateLineUnitPrice;
    this.setState({
      estimateLineQty: formattedValue,
      estimateLinePrice: newPrice
    });
  }}
/>
```

The test:

```
it.only('updates estimateLinePrice when changing estimateLineQty value', () => {
  const props = estimateLineProps.line;
  const wrapper = mount(<EstimateLine {...props} />);
  const inputQty = wrapper.find('NumberFormat[name="estimateLineQty"]');
  const inputUnitPrice = wrapper.find('NumberFormat[name="estimateLineQty"]');
  const inputPrice = wrapper.find('NumberFormat[name="estimateLinePrice"]');
  const oldQty = inputQty.instance().props.value;
  const newQty = oldQty + 2;
  const event = {
    target: { value: newQty }
  };
  inputQty.simulate('change', event);
  expect(inputPrice.instance().props.value).not.toEqual(oldQty);
  expect(inputPrice.instance().props.value).toEqual(
    newQty * inputUnitPrice.instance().props.value
  );
});
```

How can I simulate the change event on the NumberFormat component and change its value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out:

```
inputQty.instance().props.onValueChange(yourTestValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

the method
    wrapper.find('NumberFormat[name="estimateLineQty"]')

Is returning you a List, you need to make something like this:
    inputQty.at(0)
to get the properties and 
    inputQty.get(0)
to simulate.

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks Miguel

with const event = {
      target: { value: newQty }
    };
    inputQty.at(0).simulate('change', event);

I get TypeError: value.replace is not a function

and with inputQty.get(0).simulate('change', event);

I get TypeError: inputQty.get(...).simulate is not a function

Comment: what you get when you run  ` inputQty.get(0)`? do you don't receive a HTML node? maybe the problem is the `find` that's not finding anything. I always try to get by id or data attributes, could you use ` wrapper.find('estimateLineQty')` and check if there you can get the element?

Comment: Hi Miguel,
Here is what I get with `inputQty.get(0)`:

`{ '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
        type:
         { [Function: NumberFormat]
           propTypes:
            { thousandSeparator: [Function],`
[...]

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `.simulate('change', event);` on native HTML inputs.

In your case, you should simply call the  method directly:

```
inputQty.instance().onValueChange(yourTestValues);
```

Comment: Thank you klugio. I tried

    inputQty.instance().onValueChange({
      floatValue: 38,
      formattedValue: '38',
      value: '38'
    });

and I get TypeError: inputQty.instance(...).onValueChange is not a function...